# Linker Error while testing: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, xcode9-beta

I am working to support iOS 11 and XCode 9. When I try to execute the test suite, I receive a Linker Error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
>
> "ConstantName", reference from: - [FileATest testMethod] in FileATest.o

In `FileA.h`

```
OBJC_EXTERN NSString *const ConstantName
```

In `FileA.m`

```
NSString *const ConstantName = @"ConstantValue"
```

In `FileATest.m` I use the constant and have the import

```
#import "FileA.h"
```

Using a static constant in the header file seems to work, but I read that it is not the proper way to declare a constant.

It was working fine with XCode 8 and previous versions, but for XCode 9 Beta 6 it doesn't. Has someone had this problem? How may I fix it?

Comment: Just go to your build settings and search for valid architecture and simply add x86_64 their...

Comment: Is not that simple, actually.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when running unit tests and the solution for me was to go to the `App Target > Build Settings > Dead Code Stripping` and set it to NO.

Hope this helps.